# How to convert a java fxml file into exe for windows with/with out jre

Tags: java, windows, fxml

Hello I have made a sw in java with help of scene builder. Now before I give it to the Clint I want it as a single exe. Which willl install the sw in a specific folder. My app will generate some .ser files for storage purpose. Most of what I tried so far only generate exe files which works only when java is present in the system. Can someone help me with this thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an .exe installer for a Java application, use the jpackage tool that comes with recent JDKs.

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

It will also bundle the JRE so everything is self-contained.  This is actually the preferred way to distribute Java applications.  jpackage can use the jlink tool to make a stripped down JRE, or you can provide a JRE image that you have already created (with jlink).